# Ionic Facebook Auth - iOS - App Not Setup: Still in Dev Mode

Tags: ios, facebook, firebase, ionic-framework

I'm developing an Ionic app that has Google and Facebook auth, (using Firebase). For Android, I have both working. *For iOS, Facebook is not working*. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

and in case you ask, yes, my app is live (and *contact email* set in settings):

[image]

I have also added an "iOS" app in the Facebook developer console:

[image]

And as far as Firebase is concerned, I added the Facebook app informatino into my `config.xml`:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 --variable APP_ID="<app_id_here>" --variable APP_NAME="<my-app-name>"
```

I've done everything humanly possible, and Facebook should be working on iOS, but it's not. Once again, it does work properly on Android, but I had to add in "key hashes" to the Facebook developer console for it to work, depending on how I signed my app. But for iOS, I have no clue how their apps work and there's no box to put a hash for iOS in the Facebook dev console, so I'm not sure what else I can do.

***UPDATE (Solved)***

So, when using the Ionic platform using Firebase authentication, there's an additional step needed for Facebook auth to work on iOS, and that's adding the plugin for the "in app browser". The command is below. After removing the 'iOS' platform and running this command, then rebuilding it, Facebook auth on iOS now works.

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser --save
```

Comment: do you have the same identifier for the Both `ios` and `android` apps ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to add the `Contact E-mail`  as follows :

You will need to add a contact email for the Facebook App . Select `Settings` in the left sidebar and provide a valid contact email address.[image]

and from the Description of your  Plugin it stated in one of the issue is :

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 will install the latest
>   version from npm, not the latest version from this repository.
>
> To achieve that last goal, you need to call cordova add with a github
>   url
>
> cordova plugin add https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4

[Source](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4/issues/325#issuecomment-248612855)

**Update:**

After a long discussion  after installing `In-app` Browser plugin made it to work on iOS

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser --save
```

Comment: I had stated in the question: `app is live (and contact email set in settings)`. So yes, the Contact Email is set. I also mentioned this works on desktop and android, but not on iOS.

Comment: @Kenny i do read that, just confirming you and did you look into the link which i shared?

Comment: I tried the command `ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4` but got `Error: Failed to fetch plugin https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4 via registry.`

Comment: @Kenny can you tell me the version you are using ? and also i found an intrresting point specific to the `iOS` ,https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4/issues/325#issuecomment-250671531

Comment: I believe `"version": "1.9.1"`

Comment: @Kenny did you enable `KeyChain` sharing in the Xcode ?

Comment: I don't believe so, I never read any instructions on that. I take it it's important?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154369/discussion-between-webruster-and-kenny).

Answer (score 0):

It occurs because you logged in this browser with fb account that has no permissions.
you should log out from your browser first and try again with an admin account of your facebook app.